# Row_Number() Over Order By Computer column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to do Paging and Sorting in SQL Query.

Here is the my query

```
;WITH myCTE AS 
(SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) as RowID
         From [MyTable]) 

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myCTE
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1)
```

It is working fine, but now I want to sort records by the computed column **[User Name]**

So I changed query like this

```
;WITH myCTE AS 
(SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name] ASC) as RowID
         From [MyTable]) 

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myCTE
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1)
```

But it gives this error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'User Name'.
```

Can anyone help me how to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER computed column? or how can I achieve sorting and paging records in SQL query?

Answer (score 8):

Simply refer to the actual expression in the `order by`, not the alias:

```
;WITH myCTE AS 
(SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName+''+LastName ASC) as RowID
         From [MyTable]) 

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myCTE
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @pageNumber int,
        @page_Size int,
        @page_start int

SET @pageNumber = 1
SET @page_Size = 10
SET @page_start = ((@page_Size-1) * @pageNumber) + 1
Select TOP(@page_Size)<valiables_names>,ROW_NUMBER() [Row_ID] from <table_Name> having Row_ID >= @page_start
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, you can't refer to other columns within the same `SELECT` clause, because all columns are effectively computed "in parallel", and so the newly created value isn't available. One way is to repeat the expression as Ian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22730652/15498) shows, another way is to introduce another CTE:

```
;WITH CombinedNames AS 
(
    SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name]
    FROM MyTable
), Numbered as
(
    SELECT [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name]) as RowID
         From CombinedNames
) 
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Numbered
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1)
```

But, and this is important, this is still actually broken. Why? Because you've not applied any `ORDER BY` to the final `SELECT` that uses `TOP` to select 10 rows - so you're not getting "the 10 rows that should appear on page 2", you're getting "any random 10 rows that don't appear on page 1". So we need to make another change:

```
;WITH CombinedNames AS 
(
    SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name]
    FROM MyTable
), Numbered as
(
    SELECT [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name]) as RowID
         From CombinedNames
) 
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Numbered
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1)
ORDER BY RowID
```

or if you prefer:

```
;WITH CombinedNames AS 
(
    SELECT (FirstName+''+LastName) as [User Name]
    FROM MyTable
), Numbered as
(
    SELECT [User Name],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name]) as RowID
         From CombinedNames
) 
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Numbered
    WHERE RowID > 10*(2-1) AND RowID <= 10*2
```

But note that this second variant doesn't guarantee the order of the results returned within the page.